# Acceso denegado al cargar IFrame en IE11

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Estoy insertando un iframe propio creado por mi en mi página, concretamente es una burbuja de chat, y tanto para Chrome como para Firefox como IE Edge funciona correctamente, pero para IE11 no, me devuelve acceso denegado.

lo que hago en mi página principal es llamar a un JS en el que me crea un Iframe , y una vez creado dentro del evento window.load llamo a una funcion de ese Iframe para cargar el chat, pero ahi es cuando me da el error de acceso.

El Iframe lo creo de esta manera, no se si se puede hacer de otra manera como insertar el HTML en vez de apuntar a una URL

```
//Creamos Iframe para almacenar todo el chat
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
//propiedades iframe
iframe.setAttribute('id', 'contentChat');
iframe.setAttribute('name', 'chatBot');
iframe.setAttribute('scrolling', 'no');
iframe.setAttribute('allowfullscreen', '');
iframe.style.cssText = 'border:none;';
iframe.setAttribute('src', 'https://prepro.de/client/html/webIframe.html');
```

*La ruta está modificada para mantener la privacidad del sitio al ser una empresa

Cuando llamo a la función del Iframe para iniciar el chat me da ese error

```
var el = document.getElementById('contentChat');
        var iframeDoc = getIframeWindow(el)

        iframeDoc.initializeChat(params);
```

Comment: ¿Tienes algún meta del estilo <meta content="IE=8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"> puesto en el código?

Answer (score 0):

Para `Internet Explorer` `Opera` y `Safari` el soporte de iframe esta de la siguiente manera:

- Tienen soporte basico para `iframe`
- `allowfullscreen` no tiene soporte
- El resto es desconocido, puede que si o que no

[Documentacion Oficial MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/iframe)

[Info mas detallada del soporte de IFRAME en navegadores](https://caniuse.com/#search=iframe)

Por lo que he podido ver hay mucha gente que tiene problemas con iframe en IE y en algunos casos reomendaban hasta desactivarlo. El segundo link recoge info de varias paginas oficiales, tal como he podido ver hay muchas partes de Iframe que todavia estan en desarollo o ni siquiera implementadas en IE